# How to get aframe to only upload canvas contents to texture when needed

Tags: aframe

How do I stop aframe from uploading a canvas texture every frame?

I'm setting up this canvas just once at init time yet checking calls to `texImage2D` it's being uploading continuously.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#ui span");
let count = 0;
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.texImage2D = (function(origFn) {
  return function(...args) {
    elem.textContent = [++count, ...args].join(' ');
    origFn.call(this, ...args);
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.texImage2D));
```

```css
#ui {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('draw-canvas-once', {
  schema: {type: 'selector'},

  init: function () {
    const canvas = this.canvas = this.data;
    const ctx = this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = "70px sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText("X", 150, 75);
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <canvas id="helloWorldCanvas" crossOrigin="anonymous"></canvas>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity material="shader: flat; src: #helloWorldCanvas"
            geometry="primitive: plane; width: 160; height: 90"
            position="0 60 -250" rotation="0 35 0"
            draw-canvas-once="#helloWorldCanvas">
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
<div id="ui">texImage2D call count: <span></span></div>
```

You can also just compare perf. Here's one with 100 planes with 100 canvases. On my MPB it runs at 20fps

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#ui span");
let then = 0;
function check(now) {
  const et = now - then;
  then = now;
  elem.textContent = (1 / (et * 0.001)).toFixed(2);
  requestAnimationFrame(check);
}
requestAnimationFrame(check);
```

```css
#ui {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('grid', {
  schema: {
    across: {type: 'int', default: 3},
    down: {type: 'int', default: 3},
  },
  init() {
    for (let y = 0; y < this.data.down; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.data.across; ++x) {
        const id = `c${x}${y}`;
        const elem = document.createElement('a-entity');
        elem.setAttribute('draw-canvas-once', {id});
        elem.setAttribute('geometry', { 
           primitive: 'plane', 
           height: 1, 
           width: 1,
         });
        elem.setAttribute('material', {
          shader: 'flat', src: `#${id}`,
        });
        this.el.appendChild(elem);
        elem.setAttribute('position', {
          x: (x - this.data.across / 2) * 1.1, 
          y: (y - this.data.down / 2) * 1.1, 
          z: 0,
        });
      }
    }
  },
});
AFRAME.registerComponent('draw-canvas-once', {
  schema: {id: {type: 'string'}},
  init() {
    const canvas = this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.id = this.data.id;
    const ctx = this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = "70px sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText(this.data.id, 150, 75);
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity grid="across: 10; down: 10" position="0 0 -10" />
</a-scene>
<div id="ui">fps: <span></span></div>
```

vs 100 planes no canvas, just an image. it runs at 60fps. The two samples should be running at the same speed.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#ui span");
let then = 0;
function check(now) {
  const et = now - then;
  then = now;
  elem.textContent = (1 / (et * 0.001)).toFixed(2);
  requestAnimationFrame(check);
}
requestAnimationFrame(check);
```

```css
#ui {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('grid', {
  schema: {
    across: {type: 'int', default: 3},
    down: {type: 'int', default: 3},
  },
  init() {
    for (let y = 0; y < this.data.down; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.data.across; ++x) {
        const elem = document.createElement('a-entity');
        elem.setAttribute('geometry', { 
           primitive: 'plane', 
           height: 1, 
           width: 1,
         });
        elem.setAttribute('material', {
          shader: 'flat', src: '#img',
        });
        this.el.appendChild(elem);
        elem.setAttribute('position', {
          x: (x - this.data.across / 2) * 1.1, 
          y: (y - this.data.down / 2) * 1.1, 
          z: 0,
        });
      }
    }
  },
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity grid="across: 10; down: 10" position="0 0 -10" />
</a-scene>
<div id="ui">fps: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Is it actually being uploaded every frame? Is it possible `WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.texImage2D` does a check and returns early before it gets to the part it uploads to GPU? You can check Performance Tab + flame chart and look for calls to WebGL TexImage2D.

Comment: There is no check inside texImage2D (I wrote it, see profile) and yes it's being uploaded every frame. [perf](https://imgur.com/yrgOVCf) and [tracing](https://imgur.com/xIYqGgw). What would it check for? There would be a serious amount of work to track that the canvas hasn't changed and the texture itself hasn't changed via some other means to avoid the upload. It would be as ridiculous as v8 checking for a = b that a wasn't already b vs just assigning it.

Comment: Sorry, looks like A-Frame was creating it as a three.js video texture for some reason. Will file an issue and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A-Frame was doing:

```
loadCanvas: function (src, data, cb) {
  // Hack readyState and HAVE_CURRENT_DATA on canvas to work with THREE.VideoTexture
  src.readyState = 2;
  src.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA = 2;
  this.loadVideo(src, data, cb);
},
```

Bad slip up when merging a PR, will fix.

In the meantime, you can create a three.js CanvasTexture manually and assign it to the material in a component.